# Getting file not found error running Sass and Compass as jar in ant

Tags: ant, jar, jruby, sass, compass-sass

I used the following tutorial to add compass as a target in ant: http://caueguerra.com/tutorial-using-sass-in-a-java-project

Here are the gems in my jar:

```
java -jar jruby-compass-gems.jar -S gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

chunky_png (1.2.5)
compass (0.11.5)
fssm (0.2.7)
rake (0.8.7)
sass (3.1.1)
sources (0.0.1)
```

Here is my ant target for calling `compass compile`:

```
<project name="run-compass" basedir=".">
    <property name="apps.root" value="${basedir}/src/main/webapp/apps" />
    <property name="sass.dir" value="${apps.root}/resources/sass" />

    <!-- Include jruby-compass jar -->
    <path id="jruby.classpath">  
         <fileset dir="${basedir}">  
            <include name="jruby*.jar"/>  
         </fileset>  
    </path>

<target name="compile.sass">  
     <java classname="org.jruby.Main" fork="true" failonerror="true" classpathref="jruby.classpath">  
         <arg line="${basedir}/compile.rb ${basedir} compile ${sass.dir}"/>  
     </java>  
</target>  
</project>
```

With below modifications to compile.rb:

```
# Instead of loading lib dirs, just add the first arg
# Dir.entries(ARGV[0]).each do |lib|  
#    $LOAD_PATH.unshift "#{ARGV[0]}/#{lib}/lib"  
#end  
$LOAD_PATH.unshift "#{ARGV[0]}"

require 'rubygems'   
require 'compass'  
require 'compass/exec'  

# select_appropriate_command_line_ui is no longer a valid method, so don't use
#command_line_class = Compass::Exec::Helpers.select_appropriate_command_line_ui [ARGV[1], ARGV[2], "-q"]  
exit Compass::Exec::SubCommandUI.new([ARGV[1], ARGV[2], "-q"]).run!
```

I see this error in the generated .css file after running ant:

```
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: shared.
              Load paths:
                C:\Users\aliu\workspace\ui/src/main/webapp/apps/resources/sass
                file:C:/Users/aliu/workspace/ui/jruby-compass-gems.jar!/gems/compass-0.11.5/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
                file:C:/Users/aliu/workspace/ui/jruby-compass-gems.jar!/gems/compass-0.11.5/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
                C:/Users/aliu/workspace/ui/src/main/webapp/apps/resources/sass/../../../lib/ext-4.0.7/resources/themes/stylesheets
                Compass::SpriteImporter
        on line 1 of file:C:/Users/aliu/workspace/ui/jruby-compass-gems.jar!/gems/compass-0.11.5/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/css3/_border-radius.scss
        from line 1 of file:C:/Users/aliu/workspace/ui/jruby-compass-gems.jar!/gems/compass-0.11.5/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/_css3.scss
```

The offending line in _border-radius.scss is:

```
@import "shared";
```

Notice the load path contains compass stylesheets. I find it really strange that compass was able to find `_border-radius.scss`, but not `_shared.scss`, because **they're in the same directory**. I checked the jar content to make sure `_shared.scss` exists. Has anyone experience something similar, or could give some insight to this problem? Any suggestion appreciated.

**Update**: I tested running compile.rb in the `${basedir}` directly:

```
 compile.rb . compile src\main\webapp\apps\resources\sass
```

It worked and created the .css file correctly, which means the problem lies in running from ant. Does this mean I need to somehow correct the ant run path?

Comment: This part of your path looks like it's problematic:

`C:\Users\aliu\workspace\ui/src/main/webapp/apps/resources/sass`

Note the mix of \ and /.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround at best, but I realized that while `@import "shared"` cannot be found, `@import "compass/css3/shared"` is okay, so I modified all such local `@import`s to reference the more absolute paths.